# Java - Calling Component#setName on JDialog / JFrame

Tags: java, swing, window

I was wondering whether it is a good idea to call `setName` on subclasses of `Window`.
I have noticed, that a dialog for example had the default name `dialog0`. Are these names in any way important to Swing internals? And if so, does it matter whether I set the name before or after showing the window? The javadoc of the getter/setter for `name` didn't show anything useful.

The idea was to overwrite these names in order to get a more general name for a window that doesn't contain user data. Normally I would've used something like `putClientProperty`, but since `Windows` extends `Component`, instead of `JComponent`, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally I would've used something like putClientProperty, but since Windows extends Component, instead of JComponent, this isn't possible.

You could use the `JRootPane` of the `JFrame`. It does extend `JComponent`.

```
JRootPane rootPane = frame.getRootPane();
rootPane.putClientProperty(...);
```

This will give you a unique component associated with the frame.

See [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for the general structure of a Swing window.

> Are these names in any way important to Swing internals?

Not that I am aware of.